# Upload large files Flask Nginx Uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, upload, uwsgi

I have a Flask App running on remote ubuntu server with Nginx and Uwsgi.
I can't upload files greater than ~200Kb.

To make my app I followed this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

at first I had error 413 which I fixed adding `client_max_body_size 5M;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Now I don't have any errors but still I'm not able to upload larger files. I also changed my app uwsgi configuration file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 10

limit-post = 20000000
ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
disable-write-exception=true


socket = main.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

logto= /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

What else can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have set the variables correctly. Perhaps you have the config setting `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` set in your Flask app? It would look something like this:

```py
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 50 * 1024 * 1024 # 50 MB
```

By default, Flask shouldn't complain with large requests, but if this variable is set then it will throw `413` errors when the request exceeds the specified value. Check [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) for more info.

Lastly, make sure you're reloading Nginx and your uWSGI service with these commands:

```
> sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
> sudo systemctl restart <yourservice>.service
```

The `.service` suffixes are optional.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Frank for your answer, has been some time since I opened this post. If I recall correctly the error was a bit more subtle: Flask doesn't have by default a "retry" logic builtin. This in combination with the cheapest server I could find for testing contribuite to the failure of some of the most expensive requests. Implementing a "retry" logic with the retry decorator solved my issue.